# Two results in Eisenbud's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Unfortunately, I do not have an access to the book 'Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry' by David Eisenbud, or more precisely, I only have [this](https://books.google.co.il/books?redir_esc=y&id=Fm_yPgZBucMC&q=jacobian%20#v=snippet&q=jacobian&f=false) limited access.

> Could one please quote the results 18.15 (page 462) and 18.16 (page 464)?

This would really help. I am just curious if one of the above results is referred to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070299/normality-of-kx-1-x-2-x-n-i#comment8409912_4070299) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828162/jacobian-ideal-of-f-and-normality).

Thank you!

Comment: Please, the one who downvoted my question: What was wrong with asking it?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. However, it would be useful if you gave some clues as to why you want this information (so that maybe someone who doesn't have the book can help you with the mathematics problem you are working on).

Comment: Oh, I understand now. ok, I will soon edit my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem 18.15** Let $R = k[x_1, \dots, x_r][U^{-1}]/I$ be a localization of an affine ring over a perfect field $k$. Suppose that $I = (f_1, \dots, f_n)$ has codimension $c$. Let $J \subset R$ be the ideal generated by the $c \times c$ minors of the Jacobian matrix $\mathcal{J} = (\partial f_i / \partial x_j)$, taken modulo $I$. Suppose $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

a. $R$ is reduced iff $J$ has codimension $\geq 1$ in $R$.
b. $R$ is a direct product of domains iff condition a holds and $R_P$ is a domain for every prime $P$ of codimension $\leq 1$.
c. $R$ is a direct product of normal domains iff $J$ has codimension $\geq 2$ in $R$.

---

**Theorem 18.16** Let $(R,P)$ be a regular local ring, and let $(A,Q)$ be a local Noetherian $R$-algebra, with $PA \subset Q$.

a. $A$ is flat over $R$ iff $\operatorname{depth}(PA,A) = \dim R$.
b. If $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay, then $A$ is flat over $R$ iff $\dim A = \dim R + \dim A/PA$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please. just to make sure: $U$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_r]$?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: I think so too, thank you. (Thought maybe I was missing further information appearing in those missing pages).

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your questions.

Comment: Very nice of you, thanks!