# A result concerning local rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, noetherian, local-rings

The following result appears in the book 'Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry' by David Eisenbud:

*Theorem 18.16** Let $(R,P)$ be a regular local ring, and let $(A,Q)$ be a local Noetherian $R$-algebra, with $PA \subset Q$.

a. $A$ is flat over $R$ iff $\operatorname{depth}(PA,A) = \dim R$.
b. If $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay, then $A$ is flat over $R$ iff $\dim A = \dim R + \dim A/PA$.

(The above result appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4082233/two-results-in-eisenbuds-book)).

> Is there a similar result without 'local'? (probably not?).

Thank you very much!

Comment: If the ring $R$ is not-necessarily local, you need to consider $\{R_{\frak p}\}$ where $\frak p$ is a prime ideal to calculate dimension.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate/explain what is exactly the result you had in mind? Truly, I hoped that both $R$ and $A$ are not local.